# Plane symmetries of this shape

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups

[image]

am taking my first group theory class and I find this the most confusing part. My rationale for this is that it is similar to a 4-gon.

The possible tranformations are $R_0, R_90, R_180, R_270$ (R is rotation),

Also, would this be an abelian group because rotation is commutative?

Thank you for any guidance. My current textbook does not have many examples on plane symmetries.

Comment: Does this have any reflectional symmetries?

Comment: No it doesn't you are right. It just has rotational symmetries, making it an abelian then?